# Combining full-text-search queries

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have two tables in a SQL Server database with basic fulltext indexes:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG table1_catalog;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON table1
 ( 
   name1
 ) 
  KEY INDEX pk_table1 
  ON table1_catalog; 
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table1 START UPDATE POPULATION;
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG table2_catalog;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON table2
 ( 
   name2
 ) 
  KEY INDEX pk_table2 
  ON table2_catalog; 
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table2 START UPDATE POPULATION;
```

The tables have approximately 100,000 entries.

The following two queries return immediately when there are no results:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
  WHERE CONTAINS(t1.*, '"noresult"');
-- Result in 00:00:00

SELECT * FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
  WHERE CONTAINS(t2.*, '"noresult"');
-- Result in ~50ms
```

But the following takes much longer:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
  WHERE CONTAINS(t1.*, '"noresult"');
  OR CONTAINS(t2.*, '"noresult"');
-- Result in ~22,000ms
```

The queryplans are here: http://pastebin.com/SBkgpF8X

Is there any explanation for this? Can I fix it or do I need to perform to separate queries.

Comment: Looks like the problems is not specific to using two full-text searches. The same problem exists with a single full-text search combined with another simple search. I have asked a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438556/combining-free-text-search-with-another-condition